# Difference between forward and tell in akka actors

Tags: scala, akka, actor

What is a difference between tell and forward, in case I will send the same message:

```
case msg: Message =>
  otherActor tell (msg,sender)
```

and

```
case msg: Message =>
  otherActor forward msg
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The `sender()` will be different on the receiving end.

Message sends using **tell** (also known as `!`):

`A` **tells** message `M` to `B`. 
`B` **tells** that message to `C`. 
`C` thinks the `sender()` of message `M` is `B`.

Message sends using **forward**:

`A` **tells** message `M` to `B`. 
`B` **forwards** that message to `C`.
`C` thinks the `sender()` of message `M` is `A`.

Worth pointing out is, that you can achieve the same as `forward` when explicitly setting the sender of a message using `tell`, however this is not typical Akka-style:

```
// inside `B`, when received `msg` from `A`
C tell (msg, A) 
      == 
C forward msg
```

For more info refer to the [docs about forward](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html#Forward_message).

Comment: Actually in his case above, he uses `tell(msg,sender)`, which then is the equivalent to forward. Right?

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly how forward is implemented: `def forward(message: Any)(implicit context: ActorContext) = tell(message, context.sender())` :-) Happy hakking!

Comment: Was also just having a look at the source. So easy to read up these things :-)

Comment: For example : sender ! Message is it equal to sender tell Message or sender forward message

Comment: `!` (exclamation mark) is `tell`. forward does not have a symbolic method.

Answer (score 20):

Tell sets the sender as the actor sending the message.

Forward keeps the original sender of the message.

Comment: plus 1 for keeping it simple

Answer (score 1):

> target.tell(message, getSelf());
>   final Object result = "";
>   target.forward(result, getContext());

Here,
   getself() is the self reference of the actor.
   getcontext() is the supervisor reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props}
case object FromActor3
/**
  * forward method: Forwards the message and passes the original sender actor as the sender.
  */

object ActorForward extends App {

  class ActorExample extends Actor {
      def receive = {
       case message: String =>
        println(s"Message received from ${sender.path.name}, message = $message")
       val child = context.actorOf(Props[Actor2], "ChildActor")
       child ! message
      case FromActor3 => println("Response when forwarded by Actor2 to Actor3")
       }
  }

class Actor2 extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case message: String =>
      println(s"Message received from ${sender.path.name}, message = $message")
    val child = context.actorOf(Props[Actor3], "ChildActor")
    println("forwarding...")
    child forward message
    case _ => println("Unknown message")
}
  }


class Actor3 extends Actor {
   def receive = {
    case message: String =>
    println(s"Message received from ${sender.path.name}, message = $message")
    sender ! FromActor3
   case _ => println("Unknown message")
}
  }


  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("ActorSystem")
  val actor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[ActorExample], "RootActor")
  actor ! "Hello"
}
```